# JS array append

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do...

```
a=['a',2,3];
a+=function(){return 'abc'};
console.log(a[3]);
```

Ergo I want to a.push() in a shorthand way.

Is there any kind of operator that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - and in any case, there's nothing wrong with:

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
a.push('d');
```

If you want to push a return value:

```
a.push((function() { return 'e'; })());
```

Answer (score 3):

`a.push(value)` is the shorthand way haha. The other way is `a[a.length] = value`

Comment: That may not seem much shorter, but if you're doing it with `aReallyReallyLongVariableName`, not having to (mis)type it twice is convenient.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do operator overloading as far as I know, so that isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your string to an array using `.split()`:

```
'123'.split('');
```

And then use `.concat()` to append the results:

```
a = a.concat( '123'.split() )
```

---

Of course, you can always wrap this up inside a function if you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

No, [ES5 getter-setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description) allow you to intercept assignments `=` but there is no operator overloading to allow intercepting and reinterpreting `+` or `+=`.

If you knew the content being added was a single primitive value, you could fake it.

```
var appendable = {
   x_: [1, 2],
   get x() { return this.x_; },
   set x(newx) { this.x_.push(newx.substring(("" + this.x_).length)); }
};

alert(appendable.x);
appendable.x += 3;
alert(appendable.x);  // alerts 1,2,3 not 1,23
alert(appendable.x.length);
```

but really, `.push` is the best way to push content onto the end of an array.